# How does Paging3 know which PagingSourcer/Pager to use when fetching data?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, android-paging-3

I've been working with Paging3, but something in particular that has been bothering me is that I can't figure out how the library is deciding which Pager to ask for more data. This is fine since I'm only paging one set of data right now, but in the future when I need to page more data I want to know how the library is deciding which Pager to notify when I call getItem() from the PagingDataAdapter. I've tried looking into the source code, but it's a little too complicated for my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `submitData(PagingData)` the `PagingData` you provide is what links your presenter UI to the fetching logic in paging. You get a stream of `PagingData` from a `Pager` so that's how that information is passed along. Happy to clarify further if you have any follow up here.